# MSGraph Permissions

Tags: spfx, sharepoint-framework, microsoft-graph

I am trying to allow an app to get a user's manager.  According to the documentation I need `User.Read.All` permission:

[image]

So in my SPFx, I added the request:

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [
  {
    "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
    "scope": "User.Read.All"
  }
]
```

I deployed the app to the tenant Apps Catalog, add it to a site, add it to a page and run it.  I get this error:

[image]

I then ask our Admin team to go to the SharePoint API Management to approve the new permission, but it doesn't show up in their list.  All they see is a `User.ReadBasic.All` that they approved awhile ago.

What could I be doing wrong?

EDIT:

I tried removing the app from the App Catalog and added it again, I get this dialog box:

[image]

So the catalog see's the API requests.

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect in the steps you have mentioned. Can you try re-uploading the solution in the tenant app catalog and checking if the permissions appear in the API management page?

Comment: @VardhamanDeshpande I have deployed the app a couple of dozen times trying different things.  I just removed it from the app cat and re-added it.  I posted the deploy msg saying it will have pending permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Your dialog doesn't say that the app needs `User.Read.All` permission. Have you configured the permission correctly? Here is how the `config/package-solution.json` should look:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    "name": "sp-fx-teams-220-client-side-solution",
    "id": "62ab7ec3-76ba-4df3-86a5-46908ed4837e",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "skipFeatureDeployment": true,
    "webApiPermissionRequests": [
      {
        "resource": "Microsoft Graph",
        "scope": "User.Read.All"
      }
    ]
  },
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/sp-fx-teams-220.sppkg"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I changed ti from `User.Read.All` to `User.Read` after reading more into the permissions.  I only ever need the signed in user to get the manager and the `All` lets you get anybody's manager if the signed in user's permissions allows it (aka site collection admin).

Comment: You need the `User.Read.All` permission to call the `/me/manager` endpoint. This is because you are reading the profile of another user (your manager).

Comment: Still won't explain why it doesn't show up in the API Management permissions list.

Comment: And you have updated it to be User.Read.All in the package-solution.json?

Comment: I had tried a couple dozen times before posting here, yes.  I apologize for the confusion.